odd speed results when using 10gbe and 2.5gbe
I hope someone can help with a weird issue I am seeing with my build.
infrastructure : 10gb lan & switch (cat6) short runs, 2gb/2gb from the isp over rj45 via pfsense box (only has 2.5gb nic ports). all items on the network connected to the 10gb multispeed switch.
i9 pc built with latest ubuntu desktop, fitted with 1 x 10gb rj45 nic via pcie port and 1 x 2.5gb rj45 port on the mother board. I have installed docker engine and portainer. I run a program which tests my internet connection during the day which is running from portainer.
When I use the 10gb nic and test with that my upload speed wont go any faster than 1.5gbps, yet the download gets the maximum yet if I enable the 2.5gb nic/port and turn the 10gb nic off the results are as expected being 2.01/2.01gbps. I can't understand why the 10gb nic is not achieving full speed in the same machine even though its connected at a faster lan speed but yet the 2.5gb nic seems to get full speed both ways.
I have tried rebuilding ubuntu a few times, a different card, putting unbuntu in a vm, all to no avail. any ideas why my 10gb nic cant seen to hit the max on the upload? are there any other settings I should be checking with regards to the 10gb nic?
thanks so much.
